# data binding fallbackvalue doesnt appear

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, windows-phone-8

here's is my code. The fallbackvalue doesnot work.

```
    <Image>
         <Image.Source>
           <Binding Path="icon" FallbackValue="/Assets/DefaultIcon.png"> 
            </Binding>
          </Image.Source>
      </Image>
```

Also tried this

```
       <Image>
         <Image.Source>
           <Binding Path="icon">
                <Binding.FallbackValue>
                      <BitmapImage UriSource="/Assets/DefaultIcon.png"></BitmapImage>
                 </Binding.FallbackValue> 
            </Binding>
          </Image.Source>
      </Image>
```

Tried many different things but nothing worked.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<Image Source="{Binding icon, FallbackValue='/Assets/DefaultIcon.png'}" />
```

this should word if the DefaultIcon.png is set to Content.

Answer (score 0):

If your `Assets` folder is in your application root directory, then have you tried the path like this:

```
<Image>
    <Image.Source>
        <Binding Path="icon" 
            FallbackValue="/YourAppName;component/Assets/DefaultIcon.png" />
    </Image.Source>
</Image>
```